# C#: How to dynamically get single concatenated values on mixed types by PowerShell.Invoke()?

Tags: c#, powershell, dynamic, invoke

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
Get-AppxPackage | % {
    Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package $_ | % {
        $ver = $_.Package.Dependencies.TargetDeviceFamily.Name
        $min = $_.Package.Dependencies.TargetDeviceFamily.MinVersion
        $max = $_.Package.Dependencies.TargetDeviceFamily.MaxVersionTested
        $res = $ver + " (" + $min + " - "  + $max +  ")"
    }
    $_, $res
}
```

Its output contains the package information (`$_`) as well as a concatenated string (`$res`).

While I am able to read/map the package information by `PowerShell.Invoke()` in C#, I have struggles reading the concatenated string. It shows me only the length of the string but not the string itself within the dynamic variable. I also tried reading BaseObject, ImmediateBaseObject, Properties[0] and Value but no success, so far.

Here is the C# Code:

```
public static void Test() { 
  string script = @"Get-AppxPackage | % {
    Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package $_ | % {
      $ver = $_.Package.Dependencies.TargetDeviceFamily.Name
      $min = $_.Package.Dependencies.TargetDeviceFamily.MinVersion
      $max = $_.Package.Dependencies.TargetDeviceFamily.MaxVersionTested
      " + 
      "$res = $ver + \" (\" + $min + \" - \"  + $max +  \")\"" + @"
    }
    $_, $res
  }";    

  PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(script);
  bool packageData = false;
  foreach (dynamic item in powerShell.Invoke().ToList()) {
    packageData ^= true;
    if (packageData) {
      // handle package data:
      // this works
    } else {
      // handle concatenated string
      // does not work - how to get its value?
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I would like to know how to extend the PowerShell package output structure directly with the concatenated string, if possible. I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565793/powershell-extend-an-object) by using `Add-Member` or `Select` but it did not work as I do not really know where to put the `-Name` `-Value` and `-PassThru`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by further testing the approach to extend the package structure and thereby recognized that using single quotes within the script improves its readabilty in C#:

```
public static void Test() {
  string script = @"Get-AppxPackage | % {
    Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package $_ | % {
      $ver = $_.Package.Dependencies.TargetDeviceFamily.Name
      $min = $_.Package.Dependencies.TargetDeviceFamily.MinVersion
      $max = $_.Package.Dependencies.TargetDeviceFamily.MaxVersionTested
      $res = $ver + ' (' + $min + ' - '  + $max + ')'
    }
    Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Dependency' -Value $res -PassThru
  }";    

  PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(script);
  foreach (dynamic item in powerShell.Invoke().ToList()) {
    string dependency = item.Dependency;
    // further package handling ...
  }
}
```